# pythonでtxtファイルが読み込めません

Tags: python, python3, テキストファイル

```
import re

source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source) as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data)
```

と入力してテキストファイルを読み込もうと思ったら、

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-724186bfb095> in <module>
      4 
      5 with open(source) as f:
----> 6     data = f.read()
      7 
      8 print(data)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 19: illegal multibyte sequence
```

とエラーが出てしまい、読み込めませんでした。環境はjupyter Notebookです。

テキストファイルの中身は、

```
a double line
二列
a far cry from 
～とはほど遠い
a walk of life
職業
・・・
・・・
```

というように英語と日本語が交互に入っています。
どうすれば解決できますか？

＜編集＞

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data)
```

というように書き換えて実行してみましたが、今度は別のエラーが出てしまいました

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d1531ad10560> in <module>
      5 
      6 with open(source, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
----> 7     data = f.read()
      8 
      9 print(data)

UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: そもそものテキストファイルのcodecは何でしょうか？ cp932 (Shift_JIS) でいいのですか？

Comment: あなたの「テキストファイルの中身」をUTF-8で作成すると、エラーメッセージにある`0x88`と言うバイトが現れるので、「UTF-8のテキストファイルを無理にcp932で開こうとした」状態になっているようです。`open`の`encoding`引数に`utf-8`を指定して見たらどうなりますか?

Comment: ごめんなさい、codecとうものをよく知らなくて、どこで確認できますか？

Comment: 新しいエラーは `open(source, "r", encoding="utf-8")` とすべきところを `open(source, "w", encoding="utf-8")` と**書き込みモード**で開いているのが原因では？

Comment: ＠hata エラー消えました！ありがとうございます